# Open Toggle container on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, toggle

I'm creating a website for the university and I would like my toggle container to open when I scroll to that part. Up until now I can find solutions for a toggle container to open on page load.

This is my code

```
<div class="toggle-wrap">        
<span id="eindhoven" class="toggle-title"><a href="#">Eindhoven</a></span>            
<div class="toggle_container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div> 

<script> $(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle_container").toggle();
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="toggle-wrap">        
<span id="eindhoven" class="toggle-title"><a href="#">Eindhoven</a></span>            
<div class="toggle_container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,    ed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div> 

<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      $(".toggle_container").toggle();  
   })
}); 
</script>
```

you can set scroll to div.